# Altair library | Difficulty to save a Chart in .png

Tags: python, plot, python-3.6, altair

I'm trying to save an Altair Chart in .png howether I get the error below. Could you please help me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

For information I manage to save the graph in .html and .json format, but nether .png, .jpeg, .svg aren't working. I already tried to insall `altair_saver` that returns me `Requirement already satisfied`.

Thank you for your help.

```
>>> plot.save('src/modality.png')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/installer/envPySpark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/altair/vegalite/v4/api.py", line 476, in save
    result = save(**kwds)
  File "/app/installer/envPySpark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/altair/utils/save.py", line 121, in save
    **kwargs,
  File "/app/installer/envPySpark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/altair/utils/mimebundle.py", line 60, in spec_to_mimebundle
    return altair_saver.render(spec, format, mode=mode, **kwargs)
  File "/app/installer/envPySpark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/altair_saver/_core.py", line 255, in render
    Saver = _select_saver(method, mode=mode, fmt=fmt)
  File "/app/installer/envPySpark/lib/python3.6/site-packages/altair_saver/_core.py", line 69, in _select_saver
    raise ValueError(f"No enabled saver found that supports format={fmt!r}")
ValueError: No enabled saver found that supports format='png'
```

---

### Update

After running this command line with my conda env

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge altair_saver
```

A new error appear :

```
>>> plot.save('src/modality.png')
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
    at resize (/export/home/cgilles/.user_conda/miniconda/envs/metrologie/lib/vega-cli/node_modules/vega-scenegraph/build/vega-scenegraph.js:3377:26)
    at CanvasRenderer.prototype$6.resize (/export/home/cgilles/.user_conda/miniconda/envs/metrologie/lib/vega-cli/node_modules/vega-scenegraph/build/vega-scenegraph.js:3427:5)
    at CanvasRenderer.prototype$4.initialize (/export/home/cgilles/.user_conda/miniconda/envs/metrologie/lib/vega-cli/node_modules/vega-scenegraph/build/vega-scenegraph.js:2989:17)
    at CanvasRenderer.prototype$6.initialize (/export/home/cgilles/.user_conda/miniconda/envs/metrologie/lib/vega-cli/node_modules/vega-scenegraph/build/vega-scenegraph.js:3422:28)
    at initializeRenderer (/export/home/cgilles/.user_conda/miniconda/envs/metrologie/lib/vega-cli/node_modules/vega-view/build/vega-view.js:630:8)
    at renderHeadless (/export/home/cgilles/.user_conda/miniconda/envs/metrologie/lib/vega-cli/node_modules/vega-view/build/vega-view.js:736:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async View.renderToCanvas [as toCanvas] (/export/home/cgilles/.user_conda/miniconda/envs/metrologie/lib/vega-cli/node_modules/vega-view/build/vega-view.js:771:15)
```

Comment: Could you try to create a new virtual environment, install altair and run your code in it ? Does it work ?

Comment: I just did that create a new conda env and then `$ conda install -c conda-forge altair vega_datasets` but when i run my code I still have the same error that above `ValueError: No enabled saver found that supports format='png'`

Comment: After running this `conda install -c conda-forge altair_saver` get an other error :
```$ conda install -c conda-forge altair_saver 
[...]
Found conflicts!. 
Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions ```

Answer (score 1):

In order to save a chart as PNG, you need to install `altair_saver`, as well as the additional dependencies required for either the nodejs or selenium backend. Details are available here: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair_saver#installation

Comment: Thank you, I just did `conda install -c conda-forge altair_saver` and this return me a new error to long to add here: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null`

Comment: I am getting a similar 'getContext null' error. @ColineGilles were you able to solve this?

Comment: @footfalcon Sorry for the delay. Here is how I succeed to resolve my error : https://github.com/altair-viz/altair_saver/issues/13#issuecomment-719606857  Hope it will helps